# How to get image path from id using SQL

Tags: users, wpdb, user-meta, sql

I want to use a SQL query to get some random users and display an advanced custom fields profile image. Currently with this query I get the image ID back but I somehow from that need to get the url for the image.

```
global $wpdb;
$users = $wpdb->get_results(
"SELECT id
, (SELECT MAX(meta_value) FROM wp_usermeta WHERE ID = wp_usermeta.user_id AND meta_key = 'first_name') first_name
, (SELECT MAX(meta_value) FROM wp_usermeta WHERE ID = wp_usermeta.user_id AND meta_key = 'last_name') last_name
, (SELECT MAX(meta_value) FROM wp_usermeta WHERE ID = wp_usermeta.user_id AND meta_key = 'profile_image') profile_image
FROM wp_users ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 25"
);
return $users;
```

Perhaps a join on the `wp_postmeta` table on the `_wp_attached_file` field?

UPDATE. Okay, I got it working thanks to the function suggestions:

```
foreach ($users as $user) {
     $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id = $user->profile_image );
    $user->avatar = $image_attributes[0];
}

return $users;
```

Comment: The URL isn’t stored in the database. The closest you’ll get is the relative path in `_wp_attached_file`.

Comment: You could use the [wp_get_attachment_image_src](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image_src/) function OR [wp_get_attachment_url](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_url/) function

Comment: @JacobPeattie the relative path is at least a start. How would I get that based on the image ID?

Comment: @Waterfall you need to call a PHP function, this isn't something SQL can do

Comment: Sorted, thanks!